# YouTube video Full Screen Mode looks fuzzy

Tags: video, youtube

The problem that I have is that when I view a Youtube video in Full Screen Mode, it looks fuzzy. The video was not done by me. What advise can I give in terms of how to fix the issue so that it looks good when it is in Full Screen Mode.

My thought to was to comment on making it be of higher quality video. If so, not sure what is involved. What goes into a YouTube video to make it look good in Full Screen Mode?

My question is not how to display a video in say 480p, etc. but how to CREATE the video such that it looks good when it is shown in 480p in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the 'gears' icon in the bottom right and change the quality to a higher value if it is listed, such as:  720p or 1080p.

Comment: I am talking about how to make a video that shows up good on say 480p. I know about the gears..